# Identify URL of webpage when I can only receive API calls from the websites backend server

Tags: web-services, api, security, iframe, token

So I have a tricky problem of trying to somehow identify the url of a webpage, but I only have info on it's backend server that makes API calls to my server.

I have a server that receives API calls from another server running PHP. The clients PHP server receives information from a webform on their website. I am trying to the match API calls I receive with the webpage that submitted the data. Requesting the client to add a url in the API call will not guarantee that they haven't provided a fake one.

I was wondering if there is something I could do with a hidden iframe that could receive some sort of token or cookie from my server, then pass it to the PHP server who then includes it in the API call. Then I could match the url of the page I sent the token to with the API call.

Is this practical / possible? Any other suggestions of how to solve this problem??

Comment: But do you really need the URL or you just want it as a way to verify that the API call was made from a trusted source? If it's the second scenario, then you could use OAuth to use a token authentication method, and that way, you'll only accept API calls from trusted sources, without relying on other forgeable information.